# Disable or remap <C-W>o single-window command in vim

Tags: vim

`<C-W><C-O>` or `<C-W>o` invoke the vim single-window command which maximizes the current vim split, and annoyingly (if you keep typing it by accident) closes all others.

I want to remap it to `<C-W><C-_>` which doesn't close other windows.

In .vimrc I have

```
map <c-w><c-o> <c-w><c-_>
map <c-w>o <c-w><c-_>
```

This works if I type `C-W` and then `o` or `C-O` in quick succession.
However, if I type `C-W`, then wait a second, and then type `o` or `C-O` the mappings I have set up are bypassed, and the single-window command is invoked.

Should I use some other map variation?

Comment: No. If you don't want to do what a command does simply don't type that command.

Comment: Indeed! However, I also use tmux, and use C-AC-O and C-Ao extensively to switch between panes.  It's all too easy to hit C-W instead of C-A, and lose NERDTree and your "working set" of open windows.

Comment: Windows in windows in windows and conflicting keybindings everywhere. Your underlying problem can't be solved with another set of mappings, I'm afraid.

Comment: True, but is there a solution to this?  I have multiple desktops, then windows, tabs, tmux windows and panes, and vim windows.  Applications do their own keybinding rather than delegating to a central authority; the solution would be for the window manager to handle all of this, but I don't see how that level of consistency and integration is ever going to happen.

Comment: Exactly. In the name of "power" or "efficiency", we adopt many tools with considerable overlap and conflicting concepts/implementations. If you want multiple shells just open multiple windows of your terminal. It's that simple. I know tmux is a lot sexier than that but I know from experience that the added xomplexity is too much to handle.

Comment: The problem is entirely artificial: you most probably don't need all those recursive windows. Take a moment to reflect on your workflow and maybe your tooling and see if you can make it a little simpler and straightforward.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Another thing you can do is modify the `'timeout'` and `'timeoutlen'` settings:

For example `:set timeoutlen=3000` will set the mapping timeout to 3 seconds instead of 1 (default).

Reference on `:help 'timeout'` and `:help 'timeoutlen'`.

Comment: This gets me round the fat-fingering problem, even though it doesn't "solve" the problem, only makes it less likely.  Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

The difference between mappings and the built-in two-key mappings like `<C-w>o` is that the former timeout, whereas the latter wait indefinitely for the second key press. To completely override the behavior with a mapping, you'd have to define an (expression-) mapping for `<C-w>`, and handle the second key inside the mapping with `getchar()` (which also waits indefinitely).

But please think carefully whether such effort is really needed: If you're prone to fat-fingering keys or pressing the wrong ones, your use of Vim will be severely hampered. Better learn through the quick feedback that you've pressed something wrong, and try to work on improving your muscle memory!

Comment: This explains the problem, thanks.  Unfortunately, the "quick feedback" is somewhat destructive, and I use the C-AC-O sequence extensively for tmux; it's just too easy to get confused and/or accidentally type C-W instead of C-A.

Answer (score 1):

How about putting `set hidden` into your .vimrc, so after closing all the splits they don't get closed, only put to background? After that you can list all the opened buffers via `:ls` command for example.

But regards to your mapping, maybe you could try unmapping (or yet even better nunmap - which unmaps a command only in normal mode) o first, and then map it.